# How to install a ruby gem from a git repository(using bundler) in the default gems folder rather than in a separate folder called bundler?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I clone the repo of the gem and try installing using `gem install <gem-name>`, it gets installed to the default gems directory. But, when I try installing using bundler, it gets installed in a separate folder called 'bundler' which is not considered by GEM_PATH, as a result it is not usable in irb.

I want to install that gem like the other gems using bundler, but it should install in default gem folder, like the other gems. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to install a gem(from git source) to the default location as bundler differentiates rubyorg gems and git source gems separately.

So I have managed to install that specific gem from Github using a third party gem called 'specific_install'. It fetches the source from the github repo itself and installs the gem.

To install specific_install:

```
gem install specific_install
gem 'specific_install' (in Gemfile)
```

Syntax:
`gem specific_install <git repo SSH or HTTPS>`